# Numpy create a 2-d array of sub-blocks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, block, submatrix

I have a set of (numpy) 2d arrays of size N
Each element is a 2d numpy array like

```
set_of_arrays[7] == array([[ 5,  3],
       [ 1,  5],
       [ 8, -1],
       [ 6,  6]])

set_of_arrays[123] = array([[ 5,  3,  1,  5,  8, -1,  6,  6],
       [ 5,  3,  1,  5,  8, -1,  6,  6]])
```

and so on. The size and shape of each element of set_of_arrays is known.
It turns out, that each element of set_of_arrays represents a submatrix (subarray). The question is: for a given 2-d array M, which shape is also known, we want to construct M consistent of subarrays from set_of_arrays.
How to construct the matrix M in an automatic way?
I saw the np.block() function, but the subarrays should be given explicitely like

```
M = np.block([[set_of_arrays[0], set_of_arrays[1]], [set_of_arrays[3], set_of_arrays[4]], ...])
```

However, this needs a lot of hands programming, a lot of brackets [[], [], [], []]. I dont know the number N of subblocks, but it is assured, that the (sub)arrays from set_of_arrays all has correct sizes, allowing to create the matrix M. How to do that?
ideally would be something like

Thanks for aswering

Comment: N is assumed to be something like 1000
ideally i would have something like ```M.subblock[4] = set_of_arrays[4]```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try:

```
M = np.block([set_of_arrays[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(set_of_arrays), 2)])
```