# Building an (..., N, N) numpy array from a function which returns each (N, N) sub-array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I want to build a numpy array of shape (..., N, N) using a function that returns each (N, N) block. The overall point is to build the (..., N, N) array much faster than by iterating over the first (...) indices in nested for loops.

The minimal example, with N=2, would look like

```
a = 1.
b = 2 + 3.j
def h0(pi):
    return np.array([
        [a,        b * pi ],
        [b * pi,   a      ]
    ])
```

I would like to pass, for example, (M, M) array values of pi and get an (M, M, N, N) array (call it `y`) as the output. I want to build it such that `y[i,j,k,l] = h0(pi[i,j])[k,l]` without just looping over `i` and `j`.

Clearly what I'm doing is wrong --- I was crossing my fingers and got what I deserved. I have the intuition that when I pass an array for pi, I am trying to nest arrays in an incoherent way. But I don't have enough practice/knowledge with this kind of thing to see an elegant solution.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

What I want to do is kind of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081787/numpy-create-a-2-d-array-of-sub-blocks), but the suggested use of a list comprehension would defeat the purpose (which is to avoid any type of python loop).

EDIT: The problem is that I need to explicitly set the elements `a`, which don't have a `pi` in them, to take the same shape as `pi`. Will update one last time when I figure out how to cleanly do this. (Thanks @chrslg for helping me realize that this is the issue.)

EDIT WITH RESOLUTION: Indeed there are two steps to the resolution. First, I must broadcast `a` to the correct size. @chrslg provides one way to do this below. Another is to just define `one = np.ones_like(pi)` inside the function, and multiply it by every occurrence of `a` in the array definition. Then I just use `np.transpose` to put the (N,N) axes last. The correct code looks like

```
a = 1.
b = 2 + 3.j
def h0(pi):
    one = np.ones_like(pi)
    return np.array([
        [a * one, b * pi ],
        [b * pi,  a * one]
    ]).transpose((2,3,0,1))
```

when `pi` is a 2d array.

Comment: That 'inhomogeneous' error means it's trying to make a numeric dtype array from objects that differ in shape, i.e. ragged arrays.  Lok at the `fromfunc` source.  It isn't a 'faster' iterator.  It calls the function once with array indices..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get that fromfunc isn't just a faster iterator, but I'm dumb enough about array indices / broadcasting that it isn't clear to me if they can be used to do what I'm trying to do here. I understand the simplest case, using them to vectorize a function which returns a scalar, but not much beyond that. Looks like I need to dig deeper.

I assume that if what I'm asking for is possible, it probably isn't just a fromfunc call. Any suggestions?

Comment: `fromfunc` is not like `vectorize` (and `vectorize` would be a bad idea, since it is not really better than the list comprehension that you are trying to avoid). It doesn't "vectorize a function which returns a scalar". And more importantly "whose arguments are scalar". `fromfunc(f, (3,3))` doesn't call `f` 9 times with 3 combinations of (x,y) pair. It calls `f` once, with x and y being both 3x3 arrays. So, in other words, `f` needs to be already "vectorized" (that is need to be already able to work with arrays as input. Which is the case of your example function).

Comment: It would help to have example code without any `...` (especially considering that `...` has a specific meaning in python, when you obviously use it as a synonym of "whatever"). Because it is not clear to me what you think parameters of `h0` are, and what you think `h0` returns. You replied to @hpaulj that you were aware of of `fromfunc` work, but the rest of your comment suggest that you are not. But maybe it is me that don't understand. But even in that case, that is my point: it is not clear what your function do, what you think `fromfunc` does, and what result to you expect.

Comment: So, please, provide a [mre] with a fictive, simple, example of what `h0` could be (a single addition for example).

Comment: @chrslg Thanks for the comments. I never referred the function "np.vectorize", I mean "vectorization" in its general sense: making functions map arrays to appropriately-sized arrays without explicit looping. By "parameters" I mean variables of type float or complex, defined at an outer scope. I never said I fully understand fromfunc (I clearly don't, or I wouldn't need to ask!), but I do get that it is not simply producing an iterator. I've edited the question to be more explicit. It is clearly not vectorized appropriately (again, in the general sense), which is the source of my question.

Comment: (I realize this is a bad use of the word "parameters" in a python context, and have removed the word from the question). I am now drastically rewording the question, since I think I can leave "fromfunc" out of it entirely.

Comment: The main point to understand here, is that your function is already vectorized. If it wasn't, you couldn't use `fromfunc` on it. The assumption of `fromfunc` is that the function is vectorized. This is the reason why you are told that `fromfunc` doesn't vectorized functions: because it works only with already vectorized functions. Your function `lambda jX, jY: cutoff * ((-1 + 2*jX/(nK-1)) + 1.j * (-1 + 2*jY/(nK-1)))` is already a "function that map arrays to appropriately-sized arrays without explicit looping". if `jX` and `jY` are are arrays (which they are when called via fromfunc), it works

Comment: So in your example, with the `h0` example you added, that maps a complex number to a 2x2 matrix, you expect a 2×2×51×51 result?

Comment: I wouldn't say I expect it (I know at least that much about my ignorance), but that is my goal, yes!

Comment: Ok, your new question clarify that: in such case, you expect a 2x2x51x51 result. Well, it might be just as simple as calling `h0` with the grid as parameter. Again, your example functions (h0, and the first lambda you used to create the `pi` grid) are already "vectorized": if `pi` is not a complex, but an array of complexes, then, each expression using `pi` would also not be a complex, but arrays of complexes. And therefore. 51x51 in your example. So, with the provided h0, you would create a 2x2 array of 51x51 arrays. Aka a 2x2x51x51 array

Comment: That's what I'd hoped, but unfortunately not: it throws the same ValueError (`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (6, 6) + inhomogeneous part.`)

Comment: Well, can't say why, since with the given example, it works. But the reason why it could happen could be because the 4 expressions you put in a 2x2 matrix `a * pi`, `b * pi.conjugate()`, `b.conjugate() * pi` and `a * pi` might not have the same dimensions.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are just scalar (complex) then, it should work (and it does when I try). `pi` is a 51×51 array. So, `a*pi`, `b*pi.conjugate()`, etc. are all 51×51 arrays. And a 2x2 array of 51x51 arrays is a 2x2x51x51 array. Now, if, for example, `a` is a, say, 2x1x1 array, then `a*pi` would be a 2x51x51 array and, if b is scalar, `b.conjugte()*pi`  remains a 51x51 array. And then you have an array of unhomogeneous arrays

Comment: You're right. After playing around more, I found the breakdown --- the point is that some elements are just floats or complexes, but don't get multiplied by pi to set the dimensions correctly, and they don't broadcast to the size of pi automatically. I think this tells me what to do though, I need to explicitly get the shape of pi and then set those elements to be blocks of the right size...

Comment: Ok. So my answer (that I wrote while you were typing this last comment) is mostly saying the same thing. I let it anyway, since it clarifies a thing or 2 about broadcasting. But while I am talking about broadcasting (I could edit my answer, if you edit your question to include example of failing cases): you can use `broadcast_to` to make all your parameters homogeneous. `broadcast_to(1, pi.shape)` is a 51x51 arrays of 1. `broadcast_to(pi, pi.shape)` is just `pi`. `broadcast_to(np.arange(51), pi.shape)` is also a 51x51 array.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, since comments are not adapted to provide code, here is my working code

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

a=3
b=2+3.j

def h0(pi):
    return np.array([
        [a * pi, b * pi.conjugate()],
        [b.conjugate() * pi, a * pi]
    ])

nK = 51
cutoff = 0.5
def f1():
    return np.fromfunction(
        lambda jX, jY: cutoff * ((-1 + 2*jX/(nK-1)) + 1.j * (-1 + 2*jY/(nK-1))),
        (nK, nK),
        dtype=complex
    )

piff = f1()
t1=timeit.timeit(f1, number=10000)

def f2():
    jX=np.arange(nK)[:, None]
    jY=np.arange(nK)[None, :]
    return cutoff * ((-1 + 2*jX/(nK-1)) + 1.j * (-1 + 2*jY/(nK-1)))

pi2=f2()
t2=timeit.timeit(f2, number=10000)

print("fromfunc timing:", t1, "broadcast timing", t2)
print("result difference", np.abs(piff-pi2).sum())


h0grid=h0(pi2)
print("h0grid shape", h0grid.shape)
```

I also (since I started typing that before you changed your question) include a clarification on what is `fromfunc`. Basically what fromfunc does is what I do in `f2` (not just the same result. Also the same method: create arrays for `jX` and `jY`, and call the lambda with those arrays as parameters. Both `f1` and `f2` would fail if the lambda function was not already "vectorized", that is able to work with scalar parameter as well as with arrays parameters).

You can see that, timing wise, f2 is faster (3 times faster on my machine. So it worth trying). That is still a log, and enough to avoid using `fromfunc` when you can do it my way. But, yet, that is not a huge factor. As it would have been if `fromfunc` were a function that call the lambda 51x51 times to create an array of 51x51 result (usually when people do such thing, with for loops, or with vectorize, or with applyalongaxis, or..., and we give them a way to do it with a vectorized function, time factor is more in the order of magnitude of 1000, not 3. So that "only 3 factor" is proof that fromfunc does really nothing more than my `f2`. As for why it is slower, not sure, but I would say that it might be because it builts 2 51x51 arrays for jX and jY, while I use 51x1 and 1x51 arrays, and let broadcasting do its thing. Not that building the 51x51 array cost a lot. But since the broadcasting doesn't occur for all operations, only when `jX` and `jy` are combined, it is 51 times less operations for some part of the computation)

So, big parenthesis, but since I already wrote the code...

Now, whatever way you create your 51x51 grid, as long as your function mapping a scalar to a 2x2 matrix of scalars is vectorized, that it is also mapping a 51x51 matrix to a 2x2 matrix of 51x51 matrices. Aka a 2x2x51x51 array.

If it doesn't work in your case, that has to be because of differences between your actual code and the one you posted. Because, this is your code. And it works.